# has_many :through association issue in rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

`user` has_many `project` and `project` has many `user`.

`project_user` table has attribute `project_id` and `user_id`.

using devise gem for users.

when ever a user creates new project, project gets created by users. but project is not seen by user in `index.html.erb` view.

here is my code:
project.rb

```
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :users, through: :project_users
```

project_user.rb

```
class ProjectUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

user.rb

```
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :projects, through: :project_users
```

projects_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save

        format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
      params.require(:project).permit(:project_name, :from_date, :to_date)
```

index.html.erb#project

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
<% end %>
```

form.html.erb(project)

```
<%= form_with(model: project, :html => {:id => 'project-form-validation'}, local: true) do |form| %>

<div class="row select-date-wrapper">
  <div class="field columns large-6">
    <%= form.label :project_name,:class=>"required" %>
    <%= form.text_field :project_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field columns large-2">
    <%= form.label :from_date,:class=>"required" %>
    <%= form.text_field :from_date, class: 'datepicker', readonly: 'true' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field columns large-1"></div>

  <div class="field columns large-2">
    <%= form.label :to_date,:class=>"required" %>
    <%= form.text_field :to_date, class: 'datepicker', readonly: 'true' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field columns large-1"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="actions columns button-right">
    <br>
    <%= form.submit :class => "button primary" %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @jvillian, i am not able to see ```projects``` created by current user in their view.

Comment: @jvillian, current user who creates project is not able to see their project in my current ```has_many``` to ```has_many``` association. as i see i projects get created but mapping in ```project_user``` table doesn't to get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the created project to the projects of the user. I think you can do the following:

```rb
if @project.save
  current_user.project_users.create(project: @project)
  # rest of the code
end
```

Comment: getting errrr  ```undefined method `user_projects' for #<User:0x00007f8c609c0b50>```

Comment: I updated the answer, it's `current_user.project_users.....`

Comment: @rock :- You don't need `user_id` in projects table, as you have Many to Many relationship & not One to Many relationship.